# can i target a :hover function in css after onclick javascript effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So when i hover over the menu the background turns red and the text turns white.
When i click on the dropdown link the second UL is being displayed.
I wish to target the LI item .dropdown:hover as soon as i click on it. And set it to no hover.

is this done in css or javascript?
I have been trying arround with both but cant seem to target the right li.

```js
let menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-Btn");
let menu = document.querySelector(".mainMenu");
// Button toggle-menu
menuBtn.onclick = ()=>{
    if (menu.classList.contains("show")){
        menu.classList.remove("show");
    } else {
        menu.classList.add("show");
    }
}
// Dropdown menu
let toggle = document.querySelector(".dropdown");
let sub = document.querySelector(".submenu");
toggle.onclick = ()=>{
    if (sub.classList.contains("show")){
        sub.classList.remove("show");
    } else {
        sub.classList.add("show");
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #b3b3b3;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
header {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.headerContainer, .container {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.headerContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.headerBrand a {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.headerBrand a img {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
header nav {
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
header nav::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 10px;}
header nav::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background: #f1f1f1;}
header nav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background: #888; }
header nav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {background: #555;}

header nav .mainMenu {
    padding: 15px;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
header nav .mainMenu.show {
    display: block;
}
header nav ul li {
    padding: 5px 0;
    background:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-bottom:1px solid rgb(179, 179, 179);
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
header nav ul li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
header nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
header nav ul li.activepage {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
header nav ul li.activepage a {
    color: white;
}
header nav ul li.dropdown a i {
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px; 
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute; 
}
header nav .mainMenu .submenu {
    display: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0%;
}
header nav .mainMenu .submenu.show {
    display: block;
}

header nav .mainMenu li .submenu li {
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
header nav .mainMenu li .submenu li a {
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.menu-Btn {
    width: 35px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-Btn i {
    color: white;
}
header nav ul li:hover {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
header nav ul li:hover a {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a9b20b17fc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<header>
            <div class="headerContainer">
                <div class="headerBrand">
                    <a href="#">Logo</a>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="mainMenu">
                        <li class="activepage"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#">Dropdown<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">some link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">some link</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">some link</a></li>
                                
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="menu-Btn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- END header -->
            <div class="container">
                <section>
                    test
                </section>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a active class with javascript

```js
let menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-Btn");
let menu = document.querySelector(".mainMenu");
// Button toggle-menu
menuBtn.onclick = ()=>{
    if (menu.classList.contains("show")){
        menu.classList.remove("show");
    } else {
        menu.classList.add("show");
    }
}
// Dropdown menu
let toggle = document.querySelector(".dropdown");
let sub = document.querySelector(".submenu");
toggle.onclick = ()=>{
    if (sub.classList.contains("show")){
        sub.classList.remove("show");
        toggle.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
        sub.classList.add("show");
        toggle.classList.add("active");
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #b3b3b3;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
header {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.headerContainer, .container {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.headerContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.headerBrand a {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.headerBrand a img {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
header nav {
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
header nav::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 10px;}
header nav::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background: #f1f1f1;}
header nav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background: #888; }
header nav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {background: #555;}

header nav .mainMenu {
    padding: 15px;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
header nav .mainMenu.show {
    display: block;
}
header nav ul li {
    padding: 5px 0;
    background:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-bottom:1px solid rgb(179, 179, 179);
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
header nav ul li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
header nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
header nav ul li.activepage {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
header nav ul li.activepage a {
    color: white;
}
header nav ul li.dropdown a i {
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px; 
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute; 
}
header nav .mainMenu .submenu {
    display: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0%;
}
header nav .mainMenu .submenu.show {
    display: block;
}

header nav .mainMenu li .submenu li {
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
header nav .mainMenu li .submenu li a {
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.menu-Btn {
    width: 35px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-Btn i {
    color: white;
}
header nav ul li:not(.active):hover {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
header nav ul li:not(.active):hover a {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
    <head> 
       <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a9b20b17fc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- header -->
        <header>
            <div class="headerContainer">
                <div class="headerBrand">
                    <a href="#">Logo</a>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="mainMenu">
                        <li class="activepage"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#">DROPDOWN<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">another link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">another link</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Manother link</a></li>
                                
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">another link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="menu-Btn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- END header -->
            <div class="container">
                <section>
                    test
                </section>
            </div>
</body>
```